# Entity Framework/MVC4 - Relation with multiple column key

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to EF and am having trouble figuring how to set up relationship between my main table Investors, with contact information, and a table Notes which can have many notes per investor.  Here are the models:

```
public class Investor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Cell { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Address 1")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Address 2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    [StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "State must be 2 characters")]
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string ContactTableId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContactTableId, ContactId")]
    public virtual List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Note
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string ContactTableId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int? ContactId { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

My attempt as setting this up, as above, generated the error 'The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.'  on the statement:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Investors.ToList());
}
```

in the controller.  How do I set this up to make it pull the Notes automagically.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key is not "ContactTableId, ContactId", it is the single field `Investor_Id` in table `Note` (or Notes). EF thinks you try to map the single key to two field and coins this somewhat elusive exception message. But just remove the `ForeignKey` attribute and EF will use the foreign key field in `Note`.

Comment: OK, I took the Foreign Key part out, and now in the following code in the View:                                                    @foreach (var p in Model.Notes)
    {
        if (@p.note != null) {
            <p>@p.DateCreated - @p.note</p>
        }
    }
I get the error "Invalid column name 'Investor_Id'" (3 times).  Something is not connecting up right.

Comment: Well, the column should be in the database of course. If it isn't you should either add it or tell EF the correct name of the FK field.

Comment: Id in Investor goes to ContactId in Notes, and ContactTableId in Investor goes to ContactTableId in Notes.  I have taken the Foreign Key attribute out, so how do I tell EF how to map the keys.

Comment: I thought this was possible, but no, in EF you have to map a foreign key to a primary key. So you can't do without an `Investor_Id` in Note. That is better normalized anyway, because then `ContactTableId` is only stored in `Investor`.

Comment: OK, the thing is I have several other table/models I want to use with Notes.  That is why I have the ContactTableId there, to tell which table it is associated with.  For example, there is a Sellers table.  So, it seems awkward to have to have an Investor_Id, a Seller_Id for the Seller table, and so on for all the tables.  Surely, there is an easier way.

Comment: Just to see what would happen, I put InvestorId in the Notes table, and populated it with some values.  It seems the results are inconsistent in that it doesn't always pull up multiple Notes for the Investor.  Sometimes only retrieves the first one and ignores others of the same key value.

Comment: Probably a mapping issue. Look for patterns to solve _polymorphic associations_ in entity framework.